# Split monthly fix value to days and countries in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4b969b9cb1aebab114a40ab5e55224ad)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    country VARCHAR(255),
    sales_date DATE,
    sales_volume DECIMAL,
    fix_costs DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO sales
(country, sales_date, sales_volume, fix_costs
)
VALUES 

('DE', '2020-01-03', '500', '2000'),
('NL', '2020-01-03', '320', '2000'),
('FR', '2020-01-03', '350', '2000'),
('None', '2020-01-31', '0', '2000'),

('DE', '2020-02-15', '0', '5000'),
('NL', '2020-02-15', '0', '5000'),
('FR', '2020-02-15', '0', '5000'),
('None', '2020-02-29', '0', '5000'),

('DE', '2020-03-27', '180', '4000'),
('NL', '2020-03-27', '670', '4000'),
('FR', '2020-03-27', '970', '4000'),
('None', '2020-03-31', '0', '4000');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
sales_date   |   country    |   sales_volume   |     used_fix_costs
-------------|--------------|------------------|------------------------------------------
2020-01-03   |     DE       |       500        |     37.95  (= 2000/31 = 64.5 x 0.59)
2020-01-03   |     FR       |       350        |     26.57  (= 2000/31 = 64.5 x 0.41)
2020-01-03   |     NL       |       320        |      0.00
-------------|--------------|------------------|------------------------------------------
2020-02-15   |     DE       |         0        |     86.21  (= 5000/28 = 172.4 x 0.50)  
2020-02-15   |     FR       |         0        |     86.21  (= 5000/28 = 172.4 x 0.50)  
2020-02-15   |     NL       |         0        |      0.00
-------------|--------------|------------------|------------------------------------------    
2020-03-27   |     DE       |       180        |     20.20  (= 4000/31 = 129.0 x 0.16) 
2020-03-27   |     FR       |       970        |    108.84  (= 4000/31 = 129.0 x 0.84)   
2020-03-27   |     NL       |       670        |      0.00
-------------|--------------|------------------|-------------------------------------------
```

---

The column `used_fix_costs` in the expected result is calculated as the following:

**Step 1)** Exclude country `NL` from the next steps but it should still appear with value `0` in the results.

**Step 2)** Get the daily rate of the fix_costs per month.`(2000/31 = 64.5; 5000/29 = 172.4; 4000/31 = 129.0)`

**Step 3)** Split the daily value to the countries DE and FR based on their share in the sales_volume. `(500/850 = 0.59; 350/850 = 0.41; 180/1150 = 0.16; 970/1150 = 0.84)`

**Step 4)** In case the sales_volume is `0` the daily rate gets split `50/50` to DE and FR as you can see for `2020-02-15`.

---

I am currently using this query to get the expected results:

```
SELECT
s.sales_date, 
s.country,
s.sales_volume,
s.fix_costs,

 (CASE WHEN country = 'NL' THEN 0
       
       /* Exclude NL from fixed_costs calculation */
       WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN country <> 'NL' THEN sales_volume ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_date) > 0
       THEN ((s.fix_costs/ extract(day FROM (date_trunc('month', sales_date + INTERVAL '1 month') - INTERVAL '1 day'))) *
              sales_volume / 
              NULLIF(SUM(s.sales_volume) FILTER (WHERE s.country != 'NL')  OVER (PARTITION BY s.sales_date), 0)
              )
              
        /* Divide fixed_cots equaly among countries in case of no sale*/      
        ELSE (s.fix_costs / extract(day FROM (date_trunc('month', sales_date + INTERVAL '1 month') - INTERVAL '1 day'))) 
              / SUM(CASE WHEN country <> 'NL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION by sales_date)
              
        END) AS imputed_fix_costs
        
FROM sales s
WHERE country NOT IN ('None')
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1;
```

This query works in the [DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4b969b9cb1aebab114a40ab5e55224ad). 
However, when I run it on Amazon Redshift I get this error message for the line 
`FILTER (WHERE pl.sales_Channel NOT IN ('Marketplace','B2B'))`.

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can replace/adjust this part of the query to also make it work in Amazon Redshift?

Comment: Redshift simply doesn't support `filter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to define apportioned fixed costs per day for all countries other than NL:

```
select s.*,
       (case when country = 'NL' then 0
             when sum(sales_volume) over (partition by sales_date) = 0
             then (fix_costs / datepart(day, last_day(sales_date))) * 1.0 / sum(case when country <> 'NL' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by sales_date)
             else (fix_costs / datepart(day, last_day(sales_date))) * (sales_volume / sum(case when country <> 'NL' then sales_volume end) over (partition by sales_date))
        end) as apportioned_fix_costs
from sales s
where country <> 'None';
```

Note:  You don't seem to want `None` in your results so that is just filtered out.  Then the rest of the data all seems to be on one data in the month.  If it can actually be on multiple data, use `date_trunc()` in the `partition by` clause.

For reference, Postgres doesn't support `last_day()`.  You can use the expression:

```
select extract(day from date_trunc('month', sales_date) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=900d61cd484d9ff5938b7bd126ba6301)

Comment: I tried your solution but I get an error on last_day: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b6507cc7bf115a48b1de73166395e10d

Comment: @Michi . . . Postgres doesn't support `last_day()`.  Redshift does.  Try it in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. So Redshift is not fully based on Postgres. It is kind of a mix of MariaDB and Postgres?

Comment: @Michi . . . Redshift is based on an ancient version of Postgres that was released something like 15 years ago.  Postgres has changed a lot since then.  And Redshift added a bunch of functions that are more aligned with Oracle and SQL Server.  At this point, they are kissing cousins as opposed to siblings -- and perhaps even more distant than "kissing".

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: I run your query but I do not get the same results as in the expected results part in my question: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=884b812659b7155728fe0abfa3b77801

Comment: @Michi . . . The code removed NL from the total for the second condition, but not the third.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: I do not want to be a party-pooper here but instead of the 86.21 I get 172.4 so the 50/50 condition from Step 4) is sitll missing: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f7cd7c62a0c08a7adf7405e6458010bb

Comment: @Michi . . . That was the intention of the second condition.  I fixed the typo (left out the `over`) clause.  `GROUP BY` was not the right way to fix that.